# Changing Tensorflow PTXAS location

Tags: drivers, nvidia, cuda, tensorflow

I am currently trying to custom train a neural network using tensorflow 2.4.0 with a RTX 3070 running CUDA 11.0 and and CUDNN 8.

I am having this wierd issue where I can train the model, but I can't actually get any output because when I run:

`output = model(x)`
I am met with the following message and my jupyter kernel automatically restarts.

```
2021-01-08 20:52:53.437668: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/asm_compiler.cc:191] Falling back to the CUDA driver for PTX compilation; ptxas does not support CC 8.6
2021-01-08 20:52:53.437690: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/asm_compiler.cc:194] Used ptxas at /usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin/ptxas
2021-01-08 20:52:53.438427: W tensorflow/stream_executor/gpu/redzone_allocator.cc:314] Unimplemented: /usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin/ptxas ptxas too old. Falling back to the driver to compile.
Relying on driver to perform ptx compilation. 
Modify $PATH to customize ptxas location.
```

As a test I have installed CUDA 11.1 and 11.2 and readjusted the $PATH variables accordingly, but tensorflow seems to default to using the ptxas version in the CUDA 11.0 folder.

What can I do to point tensorflow towards the 11.1 and 11.2 version of PTXAS instead of the 11.0 version?

Answer (score 2):

Add the nVidia toolkit bin directory to your path, for example:

```
export PATH=/depot/cuda/cuda-11.2/bin:$PATH
```

This should remove that message.

Comment: In my case, I had to do `ls /usr/local | grep cuda` whcih showed me the path to add was `/usr/local/cuda-11.2/bin`

Comment: @jamescampbell: This helps! Thank you!